# External url for featured image on woocommerce single product page via plug-in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a external url link plugin (http://epicplugins.com/external-url-link-to-featured-images/)  to set the featured image on a product. 
The image is showing for the thumbnails but not in the single product image page. On the singleproductimage.php page I'm not sure if I edit:

```
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' )
```

or

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );

        } else {

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="Placeholder" />', wc_placeholder_img_src() ), $post->ID );

    }
```

and if to add a hook or a variable. I'm trying to figure out what function is causing it to work for the thumbnail:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Thumbnails
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.3
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

if ( $attachment_ids ) {
    ?>
    <div class="thumbnails"><?php

        $loop = 0;
        $columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 3 );

        foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {

            $classes = array( 'zoom' );

            if ( $loop == 0 || $loop % $columns == 0 )
                $classes[] = 'first';

            if ( ( $loop + 1 ) % $columns == 0 )
                $classes[] = 'last';

            $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

            if ( ! $image_link )
                continue;

            $image       = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ) );
            $image_class = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $classes ) );
            $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_class, $image_title, $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );

            $loop++;
        }

    ?></div>
    <?php
}
```

and implement that into the single product page:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Image
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.14
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $woocommerce, $product;

?>
<div class="images">

    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

            $image_title        = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
            $image_link         = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
            $image              = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ), array(
                'title' => $image_title
                ) );
            $attachment_count   = count( $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids() );

            if ( $attachment_count > 0 ) {
                $gallery = '[product-gallery]';
            } else {
                $gallery = '';
            }

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );

        } else {

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="Placeholder" />', wc_placeholder_img_src() ), $post->ID );

        }
    ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>

</div>
```

, but as you can see, I don't know what I'm doing.